# HTML email column width changing with different email clients

Tags: html, html-table, width, html-email

I could not find a direct answer for this, so please be patient if this has been asked before.

I have limited HTML experience. The width of the table columns within the email change when opened in Entourage and Gmail on my Android phone. Gmail on my PC looks fine, Outlook, Yahoo, etc. also great.

Essentially what happens is the widths of the left and right column switch in Entourage/Gmail-droid. Left column width **should** stay at  `width="401";` right column **should** stay fixed at `width="171"` (they swap so the left column is 171 and the right is 401).

I am working with an HTML email template I picked up online with nested tables. Here is the basic code with text and images stripped out. Any help would be appreciated:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        -webkit-background-size:100%;
    }

    .bold {
       color: #61BB46;
    }

    .Main {
           font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
           font-size: 12px;
           line-height: 22px;
           color: #666666;
    }

    .Sidebar {  
           font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
           font-size: 12px;
           line-height: 22px;
           color: #666666;
    }

    a:link {
           COLOR: #592989;
    }

    a:visited {
           COLOR: #FAAB53;
    }

    a:hover {
           COLOR: #61BB46;
    }

    a:active {
           COLOR: #592989;
    }

    </style>

    <body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#666666" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    <table style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; 
    font-size: 12px; Line-height: 18px; width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 30px; line-height: 32px; color: #592989;" colspan="4">
            <div style="font-size: 12px; color:#999;"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-top: 20px;" colspan="4"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 4px; background-color: #e3dede;"><img src="" 
    width="578" height="190"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: left;" 
    colspan="4"><p><a href="" target="_blank">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="5" width="401" valign="top"><p style="color: #592989; 
    font-size: 20px;"></p>
            <p class="Main" style="margin-bottom: 1.0em">
           </p></td>
          <td rowspan="5" width="19" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td style="background-color: #592989; padding: 4px; padding-left: 8px; 
    color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px;" width="171" valign="top"><p></p></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First rule with sending HTML email use inline styles. Many clients will strip out any styles in the `<head>` tag. The safest bet is to not even bother with a `<head>` or `<body>` tag as most of the time these get stripped out. Validate your html. You have some invalid markup that many clients will strip out:

```
<td style="padding-top: 20px;" colspan="4"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" align="center">

              <tbody>
```

Should be:

```
<td style="padding-top: 20px;" colspan="4"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" 
    cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <table>
              <tbody>
```